# Selecting files based on some keywords

Tags: windows

I have a folder with 82,000 text files. The file names have multiple components separated by underscore (_). I want to remove files where a component of the name contains any of a list of keywords. For example, the file names has contains FacID_Date . The FacId has 899 unique values and I want to separate 240 of them. I have a list of the 240 FacID.

Comment: And the question is ...?